# MS Excel : update multiple Workbooks using a macro in a master spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have 30 + workbooks on SharePoint that are all copies of each other except for the filename and the folder they are in. We use these to record progress on projects as we can't put an access DB on our sharepoint (don't ask!)

I need to update the data validation on all of the spread sheets and based on history may well have other changes that need making in all spread sheets again in the future.

I've got a macro that will change the validation in the spreadsheet its in.
In a "master" spreadsheet I can create the paths to the other spreadsheets and get them opened.
But when I try to run the code (in the master) against each spreadsheet using the macro copied from the single sheet I get an error:

```
runtime error 9 subscript out of range
```

on the line

```
Set myDestinationWorkSheet = Workbooks(myFile).Sheets("Data")
```

I've checked and the "data" sheet is definitely there.  I've even copy and pasted the sheet name from the worksheet just in case.  I'm confident that the filename is correct as the line before it opens the file.  I've tried referencing the sharepoint files directly with http:// in the constructed filename and via a mapped drive (in case it was a "path too long" type error).
Here's the code (mostly a combination of stuff from other Stackoverflow answers!)

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

Dim namedRange As Range
Set namedRange = Range("Schools")

Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim mySchool As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myDestinationWorkSheet As Worksheet

' step through list of schools
For i = 5 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' build file name
    mySchool = Range("D" & i).Value
    Set rng = Range("e" & i)
    'record filename in ppm master for bug tracking
    myFile = Range("b5").Value & mySchool & Range("b6").Value & Range("b7").Value & mySchool & Range("b8").Value
    'get filename
    rng.Value = myFile

    ' open file
    Workbooks.Open (myFile)

    Set myDestinationWorkSheet = Workbooks(myFile).Sheets("Data")
    myDestinationWorkSheet.Range("C2:J200").Select


    ' do stuff to file
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$L$13", Formula2:="=$L$15"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Date out of range"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "Please enter a date in between the values shown in Cell L13 and cell L15"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    'mark as done
    myDestinationWorkSheet.Range("L30").Value = "date validation updated 2/7/2014 CJ)"


    'save and close file
    Workbooks(myFile).Save
    Workbooks(myFile).Close

'move to next in the list
Next i

'
    Range("D5:D27").Select
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are there spaces in your workbook name (myFile)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably coming from your `MyDestinationWorksheet` variable. It's set as a `Worksheet` and worksheets do not need to have the workbook name.

I'd try replacing `Set myDestinationWorkSheet = Workbooks(myFile).Sheets("Data")` with `Set myDestinationWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")` being as you've already opened the workbook you wish to set the `myDestinationWorksheet` variable to.

Answer (score 0):

While your worksheet does not need a workbook name, it can be good practice to specify which workbook you're intending to work in. The problem is that your myFile is a file path and workbook name that works for Workbooks.Open (myFile) because those are necessary for the .Open method, but Workbooks(myFile) should have only the workbook name. You need to trim off the file path.